# Checking if 2 UAV images have similar NDVI

Tags: ndvi, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have 2 UAV images showing NDVI of the same plant field from different positions (meaning different coordinates, not different capture angle). I am trying to find  a solution in order to compare their NDVI and identify how similar is their NDVI. I was thinking of calculating the average NDVI and get one value characterizing the UAV image with one number, for instance for image_1 --> 39 and for image_2 --> 41. However, this cannot work because I don't know if 39 and 41 means similarity 99% or similarity 10%.

I have made some research and I have read paper such as [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8945394) and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0273117717304921) as a result of google search but I cannot find an answer/solution.

Do you have any better idea on how to proceed?

I will implement the algorithm in Python.

`NDVI = (NIR - Red)/(NIR + Red)` but when I implement it in UAV images, how can I recognize higher and lower values of NDVI in the end result image?

Should the pixel values be lower or higher?

Comment: The first thing to check would be that your UAVs have similar specs (same sensors, band centers and band widths). Your NDVI values are more likely to be comaparable if the Red and NIR bands are similar across sensors. However, unless you have used the same UAV, there migth still be cross-validation issues. This limitation is known even for satellite constellations such as Planet's Doves.

Comment: Your update suggests that you don't really understand what NDVI is, have you read anything about it, like https://gisgeography.com/ndvi-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last question,

If you calculate NDVI using a combination of your Red and NIR band, you will get a new band or a new array (depending on your data format) with NDVI values for every single pixel. You can use this function for instance.

```
def calculate_ndvi(image, red, nir):
    """Calculates the normalized difference vegetation index (NDVI)
    image: multiband ND array, with expected bands:
    red: (int) band number for red reflectance
    nir: (int) band number for NIR reflectance"""
    red_band = image[red]
    nir_band = image[nir]
    np.seterr(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore")  # Allow division by zero
    ndvi = (nir_band.astype(float) - red_band.astype(float)) / (nir_band + red_band)
    return ndvi
```

The higher the pixel value, the higher the NDVI. Values should range from 0 to 1 for vegetation.

Comment: Just a quick add: Does this happens to other indices? NDSI, RVI, Salinity etc? The higher the pixel value, the higher the level of the index?

Comment: If you calculate an index, then each pixel's value is the value of your index for this pixel. So yes : the higher the pixel value, the higher the level of the index. Since the pixel value **is** the index's value.
You can find a pretty exhaustive list of indices [here](https://www.indexdatabase.de/). To best choose your index, and how to make a comparison, you need to ask yourself what your final goal is.

Comment: How can I check this with QGIS?? I mean to put the UAV image that is computed via the salinity index and see if high pixel value stands for increased or decreased salinity?

Comment: I have no experience with salinity indices. You will have better luck by asking a new question or looking for one that was already asked. In the meantime, here are a couple that might help: [article 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1658077X16300042) - [article 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705812012246) Good luck!